# IntelliJIDEA is taking too much time to open a new project

Tags: intellij-idea, shared-memory, intellij-15

I have IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.4
IntelliJIDEA has started taking too much time to open any new project. It almost hangs the previous opened project for around 10-15 minutes before opening the new project.

Any ideas as to why this would have been happening?

My VMOPTIONS File has following

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

I have attached my IDEA log file on startup as well.[image]

Comment: What is your OS? Do you use any antivirus software?

Comment: Windows 10. 
For anti-virus, there is none that I know of. But there are few firewall protections do imposed on my system. But that should not be a problem, as everyone in my organization has them, and IDEA works perfectly fine for them.

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: Added an image snippet of my log file. This error is repeated multiple times on my log file. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try disabling all third-party plugins to see if the problem persists?

Comment: I require those plugins.. even if disabling helps.. I wont be able to put that into use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked by @Elias, I uninstalled the Maven Archetype plugin which resolved my problem. For now, I am keeping the plugin uninstalled.